# java - how to insert multiple array with different length into database

Tags: java, arrays, spring-mvc

I have 3 array's with different length. I need to insert the values present in all 3 array's into database table

This my array :

```
//Array1 length
int id_hutang = model.getId_hutang().length; //3
//Array2 length
int jlh_pengeluaran = model.getJlh_pengeluaran().length; //5
//Array3 length
int id_keagenan = model.getId_keagenan().length; //4
```

I will retrieve highest length among the 3 array's

```
int largest = Math.max(id_hutang,Math.max(jlh_pengeluaran,id_keagenan));
```

and place the highest length as base value in for loop

```
for(int i=0; i<largest; i++)
{
   String sql = "INSERT INTO surat_jalan (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
   template.update(sql, model.getId_hutang()[i], model.getJlh_pengeluaran()[i], model.getId_keagenan()[i]);
}
```

but I get error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

I need result as shown below

```
-----------------------------------------------
|   a        |       b       |      c         |
-----------------------------------------------
|  23        |  500000       |  3             |
-----------------------------------------------
|  4         |  500000       |  4             |
-----------------------------------------------
|  10        |  500000       |  6             |
-----------------------------------------------
|            |  300000       |  8             |
-----------------------------------------------
|            |  600000       |                |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Think about your database design

Comment: Try NoSQL - MongoDB maybe?

Comment: Try to use a "while" structure instead of "for".

Comment: @biladina assign null if you dont have any value in an object so that you can have same length for all bean classes. you can also insert the same null into database. you don't need to change any database design

Comment: @divine the problem is I cannot insert data into database because of different element length in my array and the array element is dynamic from input field..

Comment: @biladina then you can try inserting value as json into database. there are certain database that offers json datatype. if it is not available you can insert json as a string

Comment: @biladina you get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because some of your array length is less than the maximum length. this is a java exception. this exception is not related  to database

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to the title. By accepting an answer you are already marking this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fetch value out of range in model.getId_hutang() and model.getId_keagenan().

try This edited

```
int id_hutang = model.getId_hutang().length;
int jlh_pengeluaran = model.getJlh_pengeluaran().length;
int id_keagenan = model.getId_keagenan().length;

int largest = Math.max(id_hutang,Math.max(jlh_pengeluaran,id_keagenan));

for(int i=0; i<largest; i++)
{
   String sql = "INSERT INTO surat_jalan (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
   template.update(sql, 
                     (i<id_hutang)?model.getId_hutang()[i]:0, 

                     (i<jlh_pengeluaran)?model.getJlh_pengeluaran()[i]:0,

                     (i<id_keagenan)?model.getId_keagenan()[i]:0);
}
```

Now result look like -

```
-----------------------------------------------
|   a        |       b       |      c         |
-----------------------------------------------
|  23        |  500000       |  3             |
-----------------------------------------------
|  4         |  500000       |  4             |
-----------------------------------------------
|  10        |  500000       |  6             |
-----------------------------------------------
|   0        |  300000       |  8             |
-----------------------------------------------
|   0        |  600000       |  0             |
-----------------------------------------------
```

find more about
[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: yup, i forget to mention -1 in ternary operation but " < " that's cool

Comment: Also, your `i < largest-1` should be `i <= lages-1` or `i < largest`.

Comment: @mamtora thanks, it works, you save my life dude.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<largest; i++)
{
   String sql = "INSERT INTO surat_jalan (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
   String a="",b="",c="";
   if(i>id_hutang ){
    a="";
   }else{
    a=model.getId_hutang()[i];
   }
    if(i>jlh_pengeluaran ){
    b="";
   }else{
    b=model.getJlh_pengeluaran()[i];
   }
    if(i>id_keagenan ){
    c="";
   }else{
    c=model.getId_keagenan()[i];
   }

   template.update(sql, a,b,c);
}
```